# SQL query returns duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

That query returns each record twice. for example, the 'SpCall' field is primary key, and the query returns:

[image: result of the sql query]

am i missing something?

QUERY:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),BusinessRevenue.Entrance_Date,103) as
       analistEnterance,Teams.DivisionName, Teams.DepartmentManager, 
       BusinessRevenue.Team_Name, BusinessRevenue.Account_Manager,
       BusinessRevenue.Forigen_Infra_Count,BusinessRevenue.Partner_Infra_Count,
       BusinessRevenue.Networks_Adsl_Count,BusinessRevenue.Pri_Or_Siptopri,BusinessRevenue.SIP,
       BusinessRevenue.Centrex,BusinessRevenue.Hosting , BusinessRevenue.Vps_Server,
       BusinessRevenue.Mabal,BusinessRevenue.Equipment_Income, BusinessRevenue.SpCall
FROM BusinessRevenue LEFT JOIN Teams ON BusinessRevenue.Team_Name=Teams.TeamName
WHERE
   BusinessRevenue.SpCall IS NOT NULL 
   AND BusinessRevenue.Entrance_Year =2016
   AND BusinessRevenue.Entrance_Date <='30/06/2016'
   AND BusinessRevenue.Entrance_Date >='01/06/2016'
   AND BusinessRevenue.Team_Name NOT IN('xxx','yyy')
```

Thank you very much for your time and consideration!

Comment: Compare your entire two rows for spcall (20414) and ensure these two rows duplicated or not

Comment: It's a join. So, depending on what data your other table has, the resultset can contain duplicate records even if you join on the primary key column.

Comment: to remove duplicate use DISTINCT clause. For me it's right you have duplicated rows (I suppose your BusinessRevenue are more cardinality than team table)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to do a left join using a primary key of "Teams" table.
As you wrote, "BusinessRevenue.SpCall" is a primary key for "BusinessRevenue" table, but as you do a left join of "BusinessRevenue" with the "TeamName" column "Team" table, maybe more than one row in "Teams" have a match with "BusinessRevenue.Team_Name", so the SpCall is not anymore a primary key of the resulting table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SELECT DISTINCT, this will remove duplicate rows.

Comment: it dosent work, i cant figure why, maybe because the team names and departments are not distinct in Teams table,its not the best solution but maybe i will cross the information in my application

Comment: I just realised your query is selecting a lot more columns than the ones you're displaying in the picture. I'm sure there will be distinct values there generating duplicate rows. Do you need to select all those columns? If not you can remove the ones that are causing the duplicate rows.